# Google Doc Viewer Jquery is not working with Base64 String

Tags: jquery

Hi all am referring [gDocveiwer](https://github.com/jawish/jquery.gdocviewer) ,where i found a issue with base64 string . where am trying to bind this string to anchor tag as below

`<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUNCiWDkvr+DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL1R5cGU…b8A/sLSZUNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQoNCnN0YXJ0eHJlZg0KMzc0ODM0DQolJUVPRg0K" id="embedURL"> Click Here To Download</a>`

next to it  am calling script as

```
$('#embedURL').gdocsViewer();
```

if same thing tried with pdf url its working fine as expected

```
<a href="http://plugindoc.mozdev.org/testpages/test.pdf" id="embedURL"> Click Here To Download</a>

$('#embedURL').gdocsViewer();
```

Any help and direction in this are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem itself? You say it works with pdf, what happens with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring Plugin and its Logic written over their , It Came to know that `gDocViwer` is Not having a Support to play Base64 string content as a Doc.

This is how in it is been checked for for extensions.

```
       var ext = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

        if (/^(tiff|pdf|ppt|pps|doc|docx)$/.test(ext)) {
          /* Implementation contains*/
          /* Iframe with http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=' + encodeURIComponent(file) as url */
           }
```

This Clearly States that its not supporting any Base64 String .